# При нажатии b-6 выполняете функцию f6. Функция должна получать из i-61 ключ, а из i-62 значение и добавлять его в массив a6

Tags: javascript

объясните пожалуйста где ошибка

```js
let a6 = {
  b: 17,
  e: 22
};

function f6() {
  let out = "";
  let out1 = "";
  let inp6 = document.querySelector(".i-61").value; //ключ
  let inp7 = document.querySelector(".i-62").value; //значение
  for (let key in a6) {
    inp6 = key;
    ` ${(a6.inp6 = inp7)};`;
  }
  console.log(a6);
}

document.querySelector(".b-6").onclick = f6;
```

```html
  <section>
    <p><b>Task 6.</b></p>
    <p> Добавьте input .i-61 и i-62. При нажатии b-6 выполняете функцию f6. Функция должна получать из i-61
      ключ, а из i-62 значение и добавлять его в массив a6. После этого, с помощью функции f5 выводите массив
      a6 в out-6.</p>
    <div class="form-control">Input i-61 <input type="text" class="i-61"></div>
    <div class="form-control">Input i-62 <input type="text" class="i-62"></div>
    <button class="button-primary b-6">Task-6</button>
    <div class="out-6"></div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Алексей, добавляйте свой код заранее в сниппет для кода, чтобы его можно было здесь запускать. Я уже предложил правку

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let a6 = {
        b: 17,
        e: 22
    };

    function f6() {
        let out = "";
        let out1 = "";
        let inp6 = document.querySelector(".i-61").value; //ключ
        let inp7 = document.querySelector(".i-62").value; //значение
        a6[inp6] = inp7;
        console.log(a6);
    }
    document.querySelector(".b-6").onclick = f6;
```

```html
<section>
    <p><b>Task 6.</b></p>
    <p> Добавьте input .i-61 и i-62. При нажатии b-6 выполняете функцию f6. Функция должна получать из i-61
        ключ, а из i-62 значение и добавлять его в массив a6. После этого, с помощью функции f5 выводите массив
        a6 в out-6.</p>
    <div class="form-control">Input i-61 <input type="text" class="i-61"></div>
    <div class="form-control">Input i-62 <input type="text" class="i-62"></div>
    <button class="button-primary b-6">Task-6</button>
    <div class="out-6"></div>
</section>
```